# Why can I print to command line but not write to text file with docker?

Tags: python, docker

when I build and then run docker the code works fine and prints whatever I want to the command line. However, within my code, I have places where I write to a text file. My local machine doesn't reflect the text file changes.

EXAMPLE

```
print("Hello World)
```

this prints to my command line when I build and run Docker.

```
f = open("/feed.txt", "w")
f.write(str(time))
```

the feed.txt file is still blank even with this code.

What is happening here?

Comment: Is `/feed.txt` really the correct path?

Comment: `/feed.txt` is absolute path. Will write to a `feed.txt` file in your root directory (if the script has the permission to do it). Remove the `/` and should work.

Comment: The file will be written when you `close` the file handle (or use a `with` statement which handles this for you).

Comment: How are you building and running the container?  If writing to the host's filesystem is your primary task, you'll probably find it easier to not use Docker, which generally prevents this as a design goal.

Comment: If you expect Docker to write to root filesystem, then you should mount root filesystem inside Docker.

Comment: By "write to the command line", you mean to say "write to the terminal".  The command line is the string that you enter into a tty that is parsed by the shell to execute a command.

Answer (score 0):

You should share a volume folder between your local machine and container. You script is running fine but the file `feed.txt` is into containter.

Take a look at: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/